# How do you multiply or divide two series from the same dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you multiply  or divide two series from the same dataframe in pandas? I'm having difficulty finding examples.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. For some reason I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

See [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-ndarrays-lists) for plenty of examples.  In this case, here's an example of computing a third column of a dataframe from two others.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1,2,3,4], 'two': [4,3,2,1]})
df['three'] = df['one'] + df['two']
```

which results in:

```
   one  two  three
0    1    4      5
1    2    3      5
2    3    2      5
3    4    1      5
```